# How to use datetime value in an SSIS expression builder to formulate SQL command?

Tags: ado.net, ssis, sqlcommandbuilder

I am trying to use Ado.Net Sql command to select data from a table with a date filter.

```
SELECT  COLUMN1
    ,   COLUMN2 
FROM    TABLENAME 
WHERE   DATE_INSERTED > @[User::LastInsertDate]
```

Both `Date_Inserted` and `@[User::LastInsertedDate]` are of type `DateTime`. When I try to evaluate expression in the expression builder l get the following error;

> The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or
> an invalid elemnt, it might not be well-formed, or might be missing
> part of a required element such as a parenthesis.

Problem diagnosis from original revision of accepted answer:

> Here is my understanding of your question. I believe that you created
> two variables under package scope. A variable named `LastInsertDate`
> of *DateTime* data type and another variable named `SqlQuery` of
> *String* data type to store the SQL SELECT command.
>
> [image: Variables declaration]
>
> You set the *EvaluateAsExpression* property on variable `SqlQuery` to
> **`True`**. You then entered the following command `SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLENAME WHERE DATE_INSERTED > @[User::LastInsertDate]`
>
> [image: Expression Builder]
>
> When you clicked *EvaluateAsExpression*, you got the following error
> message:
>
> ```
> Expression cannot be evaluated. Additional information: Attempt to
> parse the expression "SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLENAME WHERE
> DATE_INSERTED > @[User:LastInsertDate]" failed. The expression might
> contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element.
> It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required
> element such as a parenthesis.
> ```
>
> [image: Error message]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is that the value you are trying to store in the variable SqlQuery is not enclosed within double quotes. **The string value of the dynamic query should be enclosed within double quotes.**

While enclosing the text in double quotes, you cannot use the datetime variable `LastInsertDate` as it is. You need to convert the date time variable to string but if you simply convert datetime value to string, you might land into unexpected format. To be on the safe side, I would recommend using `DATEPART` function to translate the datetime value to string of format **`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss`**. Here is the complete expression that will do that.

```
"SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLENAME WHERE DATE_INSERTED > '" +
(DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yyyy", @[User::LastInsertDate]) 
+ "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm", @[User::LastInsertDate]), 2)
+ "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd", @[User::LastInsertDate]), 2) 
+ " " + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("hh", @[User::LastInsertDate]), 2) 
+ ":" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mi", @[User::LastInsertDate]), 2)
+ ":" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("ss", @[User::LastInsertDate]), 2)
```

When you click Evaluate Expression, you will see the string with the date time value in the Evaluated value section.

Hope that helps.

[image: Corrected]

Comment: The drawback of this approach is that you can't extract milliseconds out of SSIS DateTime variable. If you are filtering by a table column of datetime format, 
you always get some delta. E.g. variable @[User::LastInsertDate] stores timestamp '2023-08-25 14:31:11', in table you have rows with [DATE_INSERTED]: '2023-08-25 14:31:11.250', '2023-08-25 14:31:11.600'. These two rows will always come with delta and timestamp will not move forward.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to store your variable @[User::LastInsertDate] in String format.
On writing to @[User::LastInsertDate] you can ensure proper formating with CONVERT function, e.g.:

```
convert(varchar ,@dt ,25) as TS;
```

Then you can just concatenate the variable with your query:

```
"SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM TABLENAME WHERE DATE_INSERTED > '" + @[User::LastInsertDate] + "'"
```